# GOM Player can't play RealMedia files

Tags: windows-7, codec, realmedia, gom-player

I have CCCP codec pack installed on my system which runs Windows 7. However, GOM Player cannot play RealMedia files like `.rm` and `.rmvb`. As I won't use any other players, how can I make GOM Player play those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "Real Alternative".

http://www.free-codecs.com/Real_Alternative_download.htm

Don't install the player when setup asks for the components. After installation you can use Gom to watch real media files.